# Turn off z-axis only in 3-d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, matplotlib-3d

I have some `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d` surface plots that I am viewing from different angles. When viewed from directly above (elev = 90, azim = 90) the text of the z-axis is all piled up on top of itself.

`ax.set_axis_off()` hides all of the axes, but I want to hide or turn off the z-axis but still see the x and y axes.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 18):

Most of the features are accessible via w_zaxis:

In this case you can use:

```
ax.w_zaxis.line.set_lw(0.)
ax.set_zticks([])
```

Comment: I was trying to do something to Z axis using `ax.get_zaxis()` and was getting an error that there is no such method. I substituted `get_zaxis()` with `w_zaxis` - it worked. But recently I'm using `zaxis` field that does the same job but is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Though this question was posted a long time ago, I did not find a good solution for this. I tried it myself then found this code below might work:

```
ax.set_zticks([])
```

Comment: How is that any different than the other 4 year old answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `w_zaxis` parameter has been removed since the first answer was posted. [As of Matplotlib 3.8.0](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.8.0.html#specify-ticks-and-axis-label-positions-for-3d-plots), this is probably the best way to do this:

```py
ax.zaxis.set_label_position('none')
ax.zaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
```